# Messages on Bluestacks 5

Tags: bluestacks, google-messages

I would like to text from my PC, so have installed Bluestacks and google Messages.  Although messages runs, when I try to send a text it says "Not sent, tap to try again"

I have set my phone number in advanced settings.  But still won't send.

Is it possible to use messages within bluestacks?  I can see potential abuse, so wondering if messages requires it run on a real phone

Comment: If this is about SMS text, how do you set the SIM on the BlueStacks? SMS is sent through carrier network, not internet. Without carrier and supporting hardware, there's no way to send SMS as done by real Android phones. Note that Google provides *web interface* for Messages on https://messages.google.com/web though, but it has to connect with your phone first.

Comment: Google Messages app routes SMS and MMS over data network, not carrier SMS/MMS network.  (Much like Apple routes their SMS and MMS over data network)

Comment: Are you sure about that? Or are you talking about the "chat features" (a.k.a [RCS](https://jibe.google.com/))? Just now I checked, I can't turn the feature on without a SIM card, so it still needs the SIM card to work first.

Comment: From postings I read Messages is supposed to route all three over data.  But app description is not as clear (seperating RCS from SMS/MMS).  If thats the case it won't run on BlueStacks.  But I wait to see if someone has a solution.